# wp_query multiple meta keys

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a search form using
Custom fields
can search the table
postmeta Show ticks and information search, type the code in the local Host But the site does not load
I use the XAMPP
what is the problem?

This is my code

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'house',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'value' => $_GET["city"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'part',
            'value' => $_GET["part"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'statuss',
            'value' => $_GET["statuss"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'typee',
            'value' => $_GET["typee"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'statuss',
            'value' => $_GET["statuss"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rooms',
            'value' => $_GET["rooms"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'wcss',
            'value' => $_GET["wcss"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'metr',
            'value' => $_GET["metr"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'minip',
            'value' => $_GET["minip"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'maxp',
            'value' => $_GET["maxp"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'tabaghe',
            'value' => $_GET["tabaghe"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rahn',
            'value' => $_GET["rahn"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'ejareh',
            'value' => $_GET["ejareh"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);
$all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($all_posts->have_posts()) :?>
    <div class="titSearchHouse"
         style="text-align: center;width: 150px;margin: 12px auto 0;background: #d0d0d0;color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'B Yekan';padding: 10px">
        display results
    </div>
    <div class="parti">
        <?php while ($all_posts->have_posts()):$all_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <!--start post wrapper-->
            <a class="post-link" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="post wow fadeInUp">
                    <div class="post-inner">
                        <div class="post-thumb">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($all_posts->post->ID, 'main-thumbnail'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <span
                            class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title($all_posts->post->ID); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                                                            <span><i
                                                                    class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d', $all_posts->post->ID); ?></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>506</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <!--end post wrapper-->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    wp_reset_postdata();
<?php endif; ?>
```

thankyou

Answer (score 3):

This probably a bit late in the game, but looking at your code you are probably not getting any results because you have not defined the relation between the queries. By default WP_Query uses 'relation' => 'AND' to compare queried meta data, which means that every single bit of metadata has to be found present in the database in order for the query to return results, so if for some reason or other even ONE piece of query data is not found in the database (or not sent to the query successfully) it will return negative results (or return no results in your case).

In a nutshell you should use the AND operator if you're looking for very specific query results (for which ALL bits of metadata should match your query), else you should use the OR operator if you're looking for something more general (which will match one meta query OR the other OR the other etc etc -  you get the idea). I would also be sure to include a negative results flag so that you can at least see whether or not your query is being sent (and returned) in the first place.

Bearing the above in mind, an altered version of your query would be something like:

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'house',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'value' => $_GET["city"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'part',
                'value' => $_GET["part"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'statuss',
                'value' => $_GET["statuss"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'typee',
                'value' => $_GET["typee"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'statuss',
                'value' => $_GET["statuss"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'rooms',
                'value' => $_GET["rooms"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wcss',
                'value' => $_GET["wcss"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'metr',
                'value' => $_GET["metr"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'minip',
                'value' => $_GET["minip"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'maxp',
                'value' => $_GET["maxp"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'tabaghe',
                'value' => $_GET["tabaghe"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'rahn',
                'value' => $_GET["rahn"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'ejareh',
                'value' => $_GET["ejareh"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ));
        $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($all_posts->have_posts()): ?>
        <div class="titSearchHouse" style="text-align: center;width: 150px;margin: 12px auto; 
        background: #d0d0d0;color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'B Yekan';padding: 10px">
            display results
        </div>
        <div class="parti">
            <?php while ($all_posts->have_posts()):$all_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <!--start post wrapper-->
                <a class="post-link" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="post wow fadeInUp">
                        <div class="post-inner">
                            <div class="post-thumb">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($all_posts->post->ID, 
        'main-thumbnail'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <span
                                class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title($all_posts->post- 
        >ID); ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-meta">
                                                                <span><i
                                                                        class="fa fa-clock- 
        o"></i><?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d', $all_posts->post->ID); ?></span>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo get_the_author(); ?> 
       </span>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>506</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <!--end post wrapper-->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php 
<!--add some error text to your query so that you at least know whether or not the query is working-->
else: ?>

        Sorry, no results match your query parameters.

        <?php endif; ?>
```

It's best to use the OR operator to begin with for the initial query, especially if you've got a complex query such as this one. That way you can actually see whether at least some of the results are being returned and weed out any potential errors. Also, working with $_GET or $_POST data it is always a good idea to check that your $_GET/$_POST variables actually contain valid data, otherwise you'll end up banging your head against the wall for a long time.

Hope this helps someone! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the relation part of your query, I'm not sure if it's the only problem but it should look like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'house',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'value' => $_GET["city"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'part',
            'value' => $_GET["part"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array..... etc,
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know, but don't have the ability comment yet, just thought I should point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'house',
        'meta_key' => {keyname}, <-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'value' => $_GET["city"],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),...
?>
```

Your forgot to place the meta_key in your query!

According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/:

‘meta_value‘ – Note that a ‘meta_key=keyname‘ must also be present in the query.

Comment: The `meta_key` is referenced in each `meta_query` array as `key`. If they weren't using `meta_query`, you'd be right! That's when you need `meta_key`, `meta_value`, and `meta_compare`.